# network path not found error on creating schtasks

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I am getting "ERROR: Network path was not found" when I try to create a scheduled task on my local machine.
I am using this command at the command prompt: schtasks /tn taskname /tr taskpath /sc minute /mo 20 /sd 09/23/2010 /s \\%computername% /u username /p password

When I give the above command without computername, username and password the task gets created perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong??

EDIT : I got it working by using the below command. I do not understand why it is working becuase I am using /ru and /rp which are remote user and remote password settings whereas I am executing the command on my local machine. And I had to give double quotes to computername.

```
schtasks /tn taskname /tr taskpath /sc minute /mo 20 /sd 09/23/2010 /s "%computername%" /ru username /rp password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you are trying to run that command as written, the target machine `%computername%` will alway return your local machine name.  By default `schtasks` works locally, unless you specify a remote machine with `/s`.

Now, if the command you are running is `/s remotemachine`, and you get that error, I believe the `\\` is not necessary.  [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx) are some examples.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am running that command on my local machine only. I am not doing from remote computer. Although I am accessing the computer through remote access. my computer name has a hyphen "-" in it. Do you think becuase of hyphen I am getting this error?

Comment: Why I am saying about hyphen because, I ran the same command on another system and its working fine.

Comment: I guess the hyphen was escaped by the double quotes.  The /ru & /rp are probably needed for the /s.  If you are running the task on the local machine, you could probably get away with not using /s (and computer name) and change the /ru and /rp to /u and /p.  I guess you need the task to run under alternate credentials and that is why you took the route you did.

Answer (score 1):

In the `/tr taskpath` argument, does the path contain any spaces?  If so, surround the path with double quotes <kbd>"</kbd>.  So instead of `/tr c:\program files\test\run.exe` you would use
`/tr "c:\program files\test\run.exe"`.

Comment: the path where exe is located has no spaces.

Comment: Is there any way you could post the actual command you're using?

Comment: schtasks /create /tn MyApp /tr C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp\bin\MyApp.exe /sc minute /mo 20 /sd 09/24/2010
/s \\%computername% /u username /p password

Comment: I just got the schedule task created by using /ru and /rp settings instead of /u and /p. This command created the schedule task. I have no freaking idea why. "schtasks /create /tn MyApp /tr C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp\bin\MyApp.exe /sc minute /mo 20 /sd 09/24/2010
/ru username /rp password"

Answer (score 1):

The `/u` and `/r` switches only apply to a remote system specified with `/s` and only used to gain permission to schedule a task on the remote system, and do not apply to what credentials the task runs with.

If you are accessing the computer through remote desktop (running `schtasks.exe` directly on the remote computer) you do not need `/s /u /p`; you already provided your credentials when you logged in via RDP. (It will fail if you provide them, because your already logged into that session.)

If you want to schedule a task on a remote system you are not logged into, that’s when you use the `/s /u /p` options. The `/u` and `/p` must have admin rights on `/s` to even schedule a task, otherwise it will fail.

If you specify `/s` without `/u` and `/p`, the it will use your current credentials, which may or may not be accepted by remote system `/s` (it fails if different domains, or domain ⇔ non-domain, etc.)

The `/ru` and `/rp` options are the credentials for the user that the actual task runs under when triggered (not the scheduling of the task) and stand for *RunasUser* and *RunasPassword*, *not* *Remote User* and *Remote Password*.